# ASP.NET Razor how to update ViewBag variable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hey guys on my Base layout I have

```
<html lang="en" jsPageObject="@ViewBag.JSPageObject">
```

Then on the view, I have:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    ViewBag.JSPageObject = "MyDetails";
}
```

I've noticed the ViewBag.Title gets updated but not the JSPageObject..

Comment: get updated, but with what ? are you setting some value from controller here ? if yes can you please show that code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably the `<html>` tag has already been rendered when you update the variable. Try setting it in your controller instead.